# How to perform U substitution when there is no direct dx to du mapping?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been asked to solve this problem using a change of variable and a power series expansion of the exponential term:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} \int_0^\sqrt2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx$

I expanded the exponential term to the Taylor Series:

$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{48} + \frac{x^8}{384}$

This then leaves me with this:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} \int_0^\sqrt2 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{48} + \frac{x^8}{384} dx$

I interpreted the "change of variable" as a reference to U substitution, but I am stuck when trying to substitute something in either the original formula or in the expansion of it.

I tried substituting $u = x^2$ in the revised formula:

$u = x^2$

$du = 2x$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} \int_0^2 1 - \frac{u}{2} + \frac{u^2}{8} - \frac{u^3}{48} + \frac{u^4}{384} ??dx??$

But I am stuck on how to convert dx to du

I calculated that $du = 2x dx$, and $x = \sqrt u$, but how do I replace that into the formula? Is that even the right question to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decided to use
$$x^2=u \implies x=\sqrt u\implies dx=\frac{du}{2 \sqrt{u}}$$

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, does that mean that my formula will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} \int_0^2 \frac{1}{2\sqrt u} (1 - \frac{u}{2} + \frac{u^2}{8} - \frac{u^3}{48} + \frac{u^4}{384}) du$ ?

Comment: @Joon. You made it !